# Removing items of a certain index from a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

If I've got a dictionary and it's sorted, and I want to remove the first three items (in order of value) from it by index (no matter what the contents of the initial dictionary was), what do I do? How would I go about doing so?
I was hoping it would let me just slice (such as one does with lists), but I've been made aware that that's impossible.

EDIT: By index I mean indices. So for example, were I to remove the items from 1 to 3 of the sorted dictionary below, after it was sorted by value, then I would only be left with "eggs".
EDIT 2: How do I find the keys in those places then (in indices 0, 1, 2)?
EDIT 3: I'm not allowed to import or print in this.

For example:

```
>>>food = {"ham":12, "cookie":5, "eggs":16, "steak":2}
>>>remove_3(food)
{"eggs":16}
```

Comment: What do you mean by index? Do you mean by keys?

Comment: Dictionary sort order is not stable (changes between different Python runs). You want to use OrderedDict that provides stable sort order in the order when the keys where added.

Comment: Dictionaries are not ordered and therefor have no "first three" items. So you have to find the key to remove yourself.

Comment: it's conceptually wrong to do such things with dictionaries

Comment: You can't sort dictionaries. You can sort a list of the items one contains though.

Answer (score 2):

Get key value pairs (`.items()`), sort them by value (`item[1]`), and take the first 3 (`[:3]`):

```
for key, value in sorted(food.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])[:3]:
    del food[key]
```

Comment: @AndyHayden `sorted` will create a concrete list separate from the dictionary.

Comment: It's still giving me an error message :( What do I do?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath It's O(n) when it ought to be O(1), if we were using a better datastructure.

Comment: @Jen it's not giving me an error. What error is it giving you?

Comment: It's giving me a syntax error every time I try to enter a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
import operator
from collections import OrderedDict


food = {"ham": 12, "cookie": 5, "eggs": 16, "steak": 2}
ordered_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(food.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)))

for key in list(ordered_dict)[:3]:
    del ordered_dict[key]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> ordered_dict
OrderedDict([('eggs', 16)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, regarding your statement:

> If I've got a dictionary and it's sorted

`dict` in Python are not ordered in nature. Hence you can not preserve the order. If you want to create a `dict` with the sorted order, use [`collections.OrderedDict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). For example:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> from operator import itemgetter

>>> food = {"ham":12, "cookie":5, "eggs":16, "steak":2}

>>> my_ordered_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(food.items(), key=itemgetter(1)))
```

The value hold by `my_ordered_dict` will be:

```
>>> my_ordered_dict
OrderedDict([('steak', 2), ('cookie', 5), ('ham', 12), ('eggs', 16)])
```

which is equivalent to `dict` preserving the order as:

```
{
    'steak': 2, 
    'cookie': 5, 
    'ham': 12, 
    'eggs': 16
}
```

In order to convert the `dict` excluding items with top 3 value, you have to slice the items (`dict.items()` returns list of tuples in the form `(key, value)`):

```
>>> dict(my_ordered_dict.items()[3:])  # OR, OrderedDict(my_ordered_dict.items()[3:])
{'eggs': 16}                           # for maintaining the order
```