# Remove an element from dictionary python based on index

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

How can I remove an element from a dictionary based on the index? 
For example, if I have

```
dict = {'s':0, 'e':1, 't':6}
```

I want to remove and return 's' and 0, such that the dictionary has

```
dict = {'e':1, 't':6}
```

I have tried `dictionary.popitem()` that removes `'t':6,` `dictionary.pop(key)` removes a key from the dictionary, but I have no way of finding the key I want to remove, I only have the index.

Comment: What do you mean by "index"? Dictionaries have keys and values, not indices.

Comment: I mean the first dictionary entry. leftmost

Comment: Dictionarys are unordered or insertordered depending on what version of python you use. There is no "leftmost" item.

Comment: duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40833183/5911972

Comment: Dictionaries are only ordered in Python 3.7+, in general though, relying on the order is a sign of the wrong data-structure. But you could just iterate over it and break at the "ith" iteration, and you'll get the correct key. Note, this require O(N) time. Or just `list(my_dict)[index]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you're doing this in Python 3.7 or later, where dict keys are ordered, you can create an iterator from the dict keys and use the `next` function to obtain the first key, so that you can use the `del` statement to remove that key:

```
d = {'s':0, 'e':1, 't':6}
del d[next(iter(d))]
print(d)
```

This outputs:

```
{'e': 1, 't': 6}
```

If you want to remove a key of a different index, you can use `itertools.islice` to obtain the key at a given index. For example, to delete the second key (of index 1) from `d`:

```
from itertools import islice
d = {'s':0, 'e':1, 't':6}
del d[next(islice(d, 1, None))]
print(d)
```

This outputs:

```
{'s': 0, 't': 6}
```

Comment: What if you want the 23rd key?

Comment: not sure if this is efficient, but works for sure `del d[list(d)[index]]`

Comment: @ggupta By calling the `list` constructor you're forcing iterations over all keys of the dict, whereas with `islice` it can short-circuit once the desired index is reached.

Comment: @blhsing what if we want to delete at an index let's say 50?

Comment: @ggupta As pointed out by the second part of my answer, you can do `del d[next(islice(d, 50, None))]`

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by iterating your dictionary.

1) if you have only one index to delete

```
dict = {'s':0, 'e':1, 't':6}

i = 0
for key in dict.keys():
    if i == 1: #assuming you want to remove the second element from the dictionary
        key_to_delete = key
    i = i + 1
if key_to_delete in dict: del dict[key_to_delete]

print(dict)
```

2) if you have multiple indexes to delete:

```
dict = {'s':0, 'e':1, 't':6}

i = 0
index_to_delete = [1,2] #assuming you want to remove the second and the third elements from the dictionary
keys_to_delete = []
for key in dict.keys():
    if i in index_to_delete:
        print(key)
        keys_to_delete.append(key)
    i = i + 1

for key in keys_to_delete:
    if key in dict:
        del dict[key]

print(dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try converting the dict temporarily into a list and then popping like this:

```
for ele in list(dict1)[0]:
     dict1.pop(ele)
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick 1 line code:

```
myDict = {"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}
indexToBeRemoved = 1
myDict.pop(list(myDict.keys())[indexToBeRemoved])
```